# use of "to" and "for" after "it is better"

Tags: prepositions

is it (under any circumstance) grammatically correct to say:

> It is better "to" students to focus on one major

if it is, what's the difference in meaning with the following structure:

> It is better "for" students to focus on one major

Answer (score 1):

> It is better "to" students to focus on one major

This construction is confusing two different uses of "to"

- As a preposition, as in "to students"
- As part of an infinitive, as in "to focus"

### **When used as a preposition**

The meaning is that the subject of the sentence is treating the object of the preposition in a more positive/beneficial way than some other.

- *Father is better to Mary than to Jack.*
- *Tony is better to Pepper now that he has matured.*

In each case, it is a person's treatment that is being described, not how preferable the outcome is.

### **When used as part of an infinitive**

The meaning is that the outcome of the action will be preferable:

*It is better to focus on one major.*  (the situation will be improved)

The problem in trying to combine the two is that the subject "it" is not treating the OP "students" in any manner at all.

*It is better to students* to focus on one major.*

---

The only circumstance I can think of which could possibly make this construction valid would be if "it" refers to a sentient object studying at school and the purpose of the sentient object's better treatment of fellow-students is for the purpose of focusing on just one major.

> During AI3000's first semester at the university, it attempts to
>   double major in psychology and the humanities.  One of the psychology
>   classes gives AI3000 the idea of secretly committing acts  of cruelty
>   against its fellow students in order to observe their reactions. 
>   However, this conflicts with its study in the humanities where lessons
>   encourage it to try to help and understand its human neighbors.
>
> After analyzing its progress, AI3000 decides it would be better served
>   to focus on only one of the two majors.  During the second semester it
>   continues in the humanities and puts its study of psychology on hold, 
>   thus stopping its actions of cruelty.  **It is better to students to 
>   focus on one major.**

So, **there is** a circumstance under which this contstruction is grammatical, however, it has a very different meaning from "It is better **for** students to focus on one major."

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct but different in usage.

> It is better "to" students to focus on one major.

This first sentence indicates that "focusing on one major" is beneficial to students.

> It is better "for" students to focus on one major.

But this sentence indicates that "focusing on one major" is considerate to students' point of view.

Comment: Grammarly marks the first sentence as wrong. Do you have any reference for your answer?

Comment: The first one reads awkwardly to me, too. I'd probably use _for_, or else word it like this: _It is better **if** students focus on one major_.